# Error could not dequeue a view of kind UICollectionElementKindCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Taking first plunge with collection views and am running into this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

The code is very simple, as shown below. I can't for the life of me figure out what it is that I'm missing.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
return cell;
}
```

The collection view controller was created using a nib and the delegates & datasources are both set to file's owner.

View Controller's header file is also really basic.

```
@interface NewMobialViewController_3 : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@end
```

Comment: [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

Comment: No, if using NIB, use [`registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618083-registernib?language=objc). But if building cell programmatically without NIB or storyboard cell prototype, then, yes, use [`registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618089-registerclass?language=objc).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the [UICollectionView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a) for the dequeue method:

> **Important:** You must register a class or nib file using the registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: or registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.

Comment: what should I do If I use the defalt UICollectionViewCell not custom one

Comment: You register the base class instead of a custom class. But you nearly always want a subclass. The default cell has nothing in it.

Answer (score 31):

You need to use same identifier between the dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier's argument and the UICollectionViewCell's property.

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

[image: identifier]

Comment: How to register Identifier for UITableViewCell added UICollectionView?

Answer (score 6):

Complementing what @jrtuton written... What you need is:

1) Register your nib file to "connect" it with your identifier:

```
//MyCollectionView.m
- (void) awakeFromNib{
 [self registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"NibFileName" bundle:nil]   forCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"MyCellIdentifier"];
}
```

2) Use your identifier to load your custom cell from a nib:

```
//MyCollectionView.m
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
    MyCustomCollectionViewCell* cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

3) Use always static NSString* to avoid the same identifiers again in your app.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5**

1) Make sure you have a correct deque for HEADER, you might be using the regular for normal cells.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath)
        return header
    }
```

2) doubleCheck the registration (ViewDidLoad)

```
collectionView.register(HeaderCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)
```

Comment: thanks... the registration is different for headers.

Answer (score 4):

i had everything 100% done correctly.
but for some reason i got the same error for an hour, then what i did is:

1. go to storyboard
2. select the prototype cell (in my case)
3. clear the class name from identity inspector, then rewrite it
4. rewrite the identifier name in the attributes inspector

simply, redid this step even tho i made it correct before, its like xcode misses something at a specific nanosecond!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift4.0**

Whenever your `UITableViewCell` is **xib** at that time you must have to register with `UITableView`.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.yourtableview.register(UINib(nibName: "yourCellXIBname", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourCellReUseIdentifier")
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please be sure to check the ViewController Custom Class correct if the project is having multiple ViewControllers. And then make sure whatever the "collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ABC", for: indexPath) as?" matches with the identifier used in Collection Reusable View inside the Collection View.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **storyboard** instead of xib, here are few steps.

1. Making sure you fill the right identifier of your cell.

[image: Prototype cell][image: Attribute panel]

2. In the ColletionViewDelegate.

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCellName", for: indexPath)as! YourCellName
       return cell            
   }
   ```
3. That's it. You also **don't** want to add *registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:* which will cause element nil error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give correct reuseble identifier in storyboard, which you have give in the code while registering the collectionViewCell.

Here is the code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ClctnVC", for: indexPath)as! ClctnVC
    return cell            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was (roughly) same as Omar's answer, except I ended up creating a new UICollectionViewCell custom class and giving the Cell Reuse Indentifier a new / different name than the one that I had used elsewhere in the application. It worked immediately after that.

Comment: In case this is out of context - here is Omar's answer re-posted for convenience: - go to storyboard

- select the prototype cell (in my case)

- clear the class name from identity inspector, then rewrite it

- rewrite the identifier name in the attributes inspector

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if you are working with storyboard set collectionView identifier in the right place in the Attributes Inspector -> Identifier field. Not under the class name in "Restoration ID".

If you are using collection view in tableView cell, add delegates to tableView cell not in the tableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

When I created a CollectionViewController, the default `reuseIdentifier` was `Cell` with capital `C`, but I made a mistake and made my cell identifier in `Storyboard` to be `cell`
They must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever try solution in answer another in issue not work but in code is correct syntax ,correct outlet UI.

You should check in you tableview or collectionview then check you maybe forget set delegate "tableview.delegate = self or collectionview.delegate = self"

```
collectionview.delegate = self
collectionview.dataSource = self
```

In my case is only you design collection overlap collection in your cell.

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old one, but I've experienced the same problem and wanted to share what fixed it for me.

In my case, I've declared a global identifier

```
let identifier = "CollectionViewCell"
```

and had to use ***self*** right before using it:

```
collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(self.identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score -1):

If you create it by code, you must create a custom `UICollectionViewCell`, Then, init a `UICollectionView` ,and use `loadView` to set the view is the `UICollectionView` that you create. If you create in `viewDidload()` , it does not work. In addition, you can also drag a `UICollectionViewController`, it saves a lot of time.